# CMake and prebuilt linaro toolchain: crti.o not found

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, ld, linaro

I want to cross compile for the raspberrypi2 using cmake and the precompiled linaro toolchain which I downloaded from here:
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

When I try to do cmake on my project, I get the following error:

```
/myhome/libs/raspberry/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-
gnueabihf-raspbian-x64//bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 
--sysroot=/myhome/libs/raspberry/tools/
arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/libc/ 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_9fb02.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_9fb02 -rdynamic


 /myhome/libs/raspberry/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-
gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../..
/../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:   cannot find crt1.o: 
No such file or directory
```

This file is present in the following directory:

```
 /myhome/libs/raspberry/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-
 linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/
 usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

My cmake toolchain file looks as follows

```
 set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/myhome/libs/raspberry/sysroot/")
 set(tools "/myhome/libs/raspberry/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/")
 set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++")

 set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON)
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}")
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
 set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

The sysroot directory is where I mounted the raspberry image. I am a bit confused about whether this should be the root of the raspberry image or a path to the linaro tool-chain.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that

```
  set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/myhome/libs/raspberry/sysroot/")
```

was an empty directory, as I mounted the jessie image to this directory but after a reboot the mount was not in this directory anymore.